# Showing different MVC3 views in Jquery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, accordion

Really have no clue, how to proceed.

I have a controller called Application which has four (4) public methods. All I want is to load a Jquery Accordion with four (4) sections, each for one of the public methods. In my accordion I want that, by default the 2,3 and 4th section will be disabled. When user fill up the form in section and click next, the 2nd section of the accordion gets visible. Same goes for 3rd and 4th section.
My Application Controller looks like,

```
public ActionResult Verify()
        {           
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult Credentials()
        {           
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult SelectJob()
        {           
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult SendApplication()
        {           
            return View();
        }
```

Is it possible to send different return value from the one controller's different methods to the same view()? How?

Huge thanks for any solution or step by step...

Comment: So basicly you are trying to show a page in a page? If so you will probably need iframes, not sure if there is anything else that replaces that these days though.

Comment: You need to change your actions to return `PartialView()` and then in the parent page where you are defining your accordian user `@Html.RenderPartial('ActionName')`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Rory. Can you give me solution about how can i then interact from one section of the accordion to show the hidden accordion section. e.g Show the 2nd accordion section when user clicks a button in the 1st section? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

I changed code for your needs. I also included newest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI to make it work.

---

Fully answer tested. I could give you the hole solution but I can't upload any files here. If you provide me a place to upload I can't place the entire solution for you.

**Controller/HomeController**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Accordion.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Verify()
        {
            return PartialView("_Verify");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Credentials()
        {
            return PartialView("_Credentials");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SelectJob()
        {
            return PartialView("_SelectJob");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SendApplication()
        {
            return PartialView("_SendApplication");
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Verify</h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Verify")
    </div>

    <h3>Credentials</h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Credentials")
    </div>

    <h3 class="disabled">SelectJob</h3>
    <div class="dynamic-content" data-action="SelectJob"></div>

    <h3 class="disabled">SendApplication</h3>
    <div class="dynamic-content" data-action="SendApplication"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        var $accordion = $('#accordion')

        $accordion.accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            animated: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });

        $accordion.on('accordionbeforeactivate', function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.newHeader.hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
            };
        });

        $accordion.on('accordionactivate', function (event, ui) {

            if (ui.newHeader.length > 0
             && ui.newPanel.html().length == 0
             && ui.newPanel.hasClass('dynamic-content') == true) {
                var action = ui.newPanel.data('action');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/' + action,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (htmlCodePartialView) {
                        ui.newPanel.html(htmlCodePartialView);
                    }
                });
            };
        });

        $accordion.on('click', '.next', function () {
            var $button = $(this);
            var $nextHeader = $button.closest('.ui-accordion-content').next()
            $nextHeader.removeClass('disabled').click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Views/Home/_Verify.cshtml**

```
This is the view 'Verify'.
```

**Views/Home/_Credentials.cshtml**

```
This is the view 'Credentials'.<br />
<button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
```

**Views/Home/_SelectJob.cshtml**

```
This is the view 'SelectJob'.<br />
<button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
```

**Views/Home/_SendApplication.cshtml**

```
This is the view 'SendApplication'.
```

**Views/_Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution looks now like this:

[image]

Comment: let you know after giving a try.

Comment: I just changed the event type from `accordionactivate` to `accordionbeforeactivate`.

Comment: By the way, which View is your "View". Can you explain which one which and where to place what? Sorry for the trouble. I am quite NEW in MVC.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english... Can you just explain the steps like, what is the initial View (at the top of your solution) doing and where should I place the JS code?

Comment: I am writing a sample solution for you.

Comment: can you send me the example file to my email address? My Email: sarwar_206@yahoo.com

Comment: it would be really helpful, if you can send me as soon as you can. Thanks a lot....

Comment: I did send it to you. Please mark this as correct answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: yah I got your mail. It was really good and helpful. Can you help to solve the full puzzle? I want that by default section 1 and 2 will be visible and 3 and 4 are disabled. When user click next in the 2nd section, the 3rd one gets enabled and when user click next in the 3rd the 4th one gets enabled.